# Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scalamacros:quasiquotes

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-pickling, scala-quasiquotes, scala-2.11

I am trying to use [scala-pickling](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/pickling/) in one of [my project](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon/tree/pickling)s. I tried to [mimic](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon/commit/12a649631af6099dd440809583da10aed0f90f9a) the build file of [macroid](https://github.com/macroid/macroid) which seems to use pickling too but I keep getting this error on `sbt test`:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in dijon:
[error]    org.scalamacros:quasiquotes _2.10, _2.10.3
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scalamacros:quasiquotes
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:47)
    at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:30)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$61.apply(Defaults.scala:1044)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$61.apply(Defaults.scala:1044)
```

Full build log is [here](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/dijon/builds/23261782). What am I doing wrong? What should I change in my [build.sbt](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon/blob/pickling/build.sbt) to fix this? I also should be able to cross compile and release my library against both `2.10.x` and `2.11.x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from 2.0.0-M7, `org.scalamacros % quasiquotes` are cross-versioned as binary (i.e. `_2.10`) and not as full (i.e. `_2.10.x`): http://scalamacros.org/news/2014/04/03/macro-paradise-2.0.0-M7.html. Looks like one of your dependencies uses pre-M7 quasiquotes and another one uses post-M7 quasiquotes.

I don't think this can fixed in any way other than upgrading all the dependencies that use the old quasiquote library, because pre-M7 and post-M7 quasiquote libraries are incompatible.

Comment: Btw it would be interesting to know where those conflicting quasiquotes came from, so that I can help people still on 2.0.0-M3 to migrate away (that should be as trivial as changing `2.0.0-M3` to `2.0.0`, but still).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using two different versions of the quasiquotes module that allows defining Scala macros. You should make sure that only a single version is used, and that this single version is matched by all your dependencies that use macros.

Also, are you sure that scala-pickling was released for Scala 2.11.x? Judging, from their build file, they released only for `2.10.3` - https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/2.10.x/project/Build.scala#L10.

First, try to remove:

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.0-RC4")
```

And try again. After that, set the Scala version to `2.10.3`, so that it matches the one in scala-pickling.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

EDIT: See Eugene's answer below for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just [did as you said](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon/commit/244676f1c9cf83e827e9f773aa5522456bc58f4c)

Here's the [build log](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/dijon/builds/23266134)

Answer (score 1):

According to my dependencyGraph from pulling in spray-testkit_2.10-1.3.2, specs2_2.10 v1.3.10 is still using a milestone release of quasiquotes. I ran the cross version error issue because of this.