# SBT, resolving modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

getting 

`error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/hehe/}my-app:
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.11, _2.10`

during `sbt clean compile`

Trying to exclude 2.10 and use 2.11:

`("com.my.company" % "has-bad-dependency" % "latest.integration").exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-scala"),
    ("com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.4.2").force()`

or 

`("com.my.company" % "has-bad-dependency" % "latest.integration").exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-scala"),
    ("com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.4.2").force()`

Doesn't help. Error is the same.

Is there any chance to fix it?

I've seen various SO QA like [Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scalamacros:quasiquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149443/conflicting-cross-version-suffixes-in-org-scalamacrosquasiquotes) which leads to https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch/issues/49

It doesn't work for me and I can't find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, sorry, I was blind.

`("com.my.company" % "has-bad-dependency" % "latest.integration").exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-scala_2.10"),`

My **artifactId** was wrong, it didn't have **_2.10**.

Works fine.